# google apps script sheet Calculation control

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to translate a vba excell script to google apps sheet

In order to optimize the algorithm, I need to stop, refresh and restart the auto calculation.

In VBA I used:

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.CalculateFullRebuild

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Is there an equivalent way to get the same functionality in googla apps?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly anyway.

In Google Apps Script though, the values are only calculated when needed. That is, you can write multiple values to a sheet, and it'll only calculate when in the end, after you've finished.

Unless your script tries to read values after it has written some (not a very good practice). Or if you explicit call `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

I doubt you're having performance problems due to automatic calculation, the whole sheet would have to get slow. Script performance problems are almost never related to the sheet performance, but just a bad code issue or a huge task (for scripts).